# How can I connect to a socks 5 proxy using a vpn,

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, internet-connection, wireless-access-point

How can I connect to a socks 5 proxy using a vpn, I want the website I am connecting to see me coming from the proxy location, proxies are banned by ISP, every time I connect to vpn and then to a proxy the browser tells me I have no internet please help I am desperate.